# How to install pgAdmin4 in ubuntu 21.10?

Tags: apt, software-installation, dependencies, pgadmin, 21.10

I am trying to install pgAdmin4 in my Ubuntu 21.10, I followed this official blog :
https://www.pgadmin.org/download/pgadmin-4-apt/

after running

```
# Create the repository configuration file:
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb https://ftp.postgresql.org/pub/pgadmin/pgadmin4/apt/$(lsb_release -cs) pgadmin4 main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgadmin4.list && apt update'
```

It throws the error :

```
E: The repository 'https://ftp.postgresql.org/pub/pgadmin/pgadmin4/apt/impish pgadmin4 Release' does not have a Release file.
```

Now if i do

```
# Install for both desktop and web modes:
sudo apt install pgadmin4
```

it throws the error :

```
E: Package 'pgadmin4' has no installation candidate
```

I read a few blogs, I found that pgAdmin4 didnt list 21.10 in their APT [download page](https://www.pgadmin.org/download/pgadmin-4-apt/). Is there any possible way to install pgAdmin4 in my system?

Comment: Security of third party repositories are the responsibility of the end-user to validate; the source you added does **not** provide support for *impish* or Ubuntu 21.10 yet, so you've added a repo that doesn't support your release - the error messages are correct - the source should be removed.